# Debugging in mobile browsers

Tags: mobile, firebug, mobile-browser

Is there any tool like firebug  to debug javascript/jquery Ajax request in mobile browsers?

How are you guys debugging things in mobile browsers in mobile devices?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/debugging_mobile_javascript_with_weinre?lang=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the device. I haven't had a chance to work with browsers on Android, but i did some debugging on iPhone and iPad. Usually most of the testing could be dove via emulator, but there are some cases, like when you have to test multitouch gestures etc when it's not exactly viable via emulator/agent change.

First, you need to activate debugging (Settings->Safari). But that's only first half of the problem. Second one has to be done in code. If data that you're trying to test for errors isn't to large, you can serialize it (usually objects) and display via console.log() command in console page (to open click on the top bar which will be shown after you enable debugging).

That's more or less it for simple cases.

Answer (score 0):

For iphone and ipad testing you can use the desktop version of Safari and change the user agent like this:

http://www.onedigitallife.com/2005/08/03/changing-safaris-user-agent/

Comment: things worked in my desktop safari browser for an ajax request for facebook connect with user agent as iphone but not working when tryin in  iphone itself.

Answer (score 0):

there is a script plugin that phonegap uses for remote debugging on mobile devices(**all** mobile devices), i suggest you have a look on it: http://debug.phonegap.com/

this allows you to debug on desktop computer mobile devices like iPhone, Android, Windows Mobile..